# What "things" is Jesus talking about in Matthew 11:25?

Tags: life-of-jesus, prayer, gospel-of-matthew, children, wisdom

I really like this verse but I don't fully grasp what Jesus is talking about in his prayer (specifically 11:25)

### The Father Revealed in the Son

25 At that time Jesus said, “I praise you, Father, Lord of heaven and earth, because you have hidden these things from the wise and learned, and revealed them to little children.

26 Yes, Father, for this is what you were pleased to do.

27 “All things have been committed to me by my Father. No one knows the Son except the Father, and no one knows the Father except the Son and those to whom the Son chooses to reveal him.

28 “Come to me, all you who are weary and burdened, and I will give you rest.

29 Take my yoke upon you and learn from me, for I am gentle and humble in heart, and you will find rest for your souls.

30 For my yoke is easy and my burden is light.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Things" is simply Truth, these Truths.

It is better to be humble than proud.
Grace is better than triumph.
That all credit for anything we achieve belongs to God.

Things like that.

Comment: Why would children have a greater understanding of this than the wise?

Comment: Children are naturally humble and honest.  No false airs, no fluffy speech, the always tell you exactly what they think.  They are not fake or artificial.  They also are very aware that they are helpless and depended, as we should be.